# FFMPEG strips audio while converting video

Tags: php5, video, ffmpeg, codecs

I have Ubuntu server 8.04 installed with the Multiverse repos enabled.

I have installed FFMPEG, with its PHP extension also.

When I try to convert videos into the flv format, I find that the audio is stripped out.

Also, audio cannot be converted to mp3, only mp2.

How do I install the codecs required ?

Please help.

Comment: have you installed the codecs and compiled ffmpeg with the options to use them ?

Comment: Not sure this is really a SF question, more suitable for SU, what do others think?

Comment: I think it is, because I am using ffMpeg on my production server with its PHP extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This old post: [ffmpeg on Ubuntu Intrepid (8.10) Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/99590/ffmpeg-on-ubuntu-intrepid-8-10-server/99682#99682) on ServerFault had my answer. Thanks folks !

Comment: This is the page where the above SF page links to. http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=8345112&postcount=636

Answer (score 0):

You need build ffmpeg from source. Read this page: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ffmpeg

Comment: I got it to work from here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=8345112&postcount=636

Comment: Add you output command: ffmpeg